# Narrow the function return type based on the return type of a function passed as an argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have an issue with TypeScript 4.9.4 (in case version matters).

I expect it should be possible to alter the return type of the function `processFooBar` below based on the type of the function passed inside.

I need to preserve named inferred type as well.

The current best attempt is below. It infers types correctly, but only when type parameters are specified at the call site explicitly, which is not good for me:

```js
import { expectAssignable, expectNotType, expectType } from 'tsd';

type Foo<T> = { foo: true, value: T };
type Bar = { foo: false };
type FooBar<T> = Foo<T> | Bar;

const fooInstance: Foo<number> = { foo: true, value: 42 };
const barInstance: Bar = { foo: false };

expectType<Foo<number>>( fooInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<Foo<number>>( barInstance ); // pass

expectNotType<Bar>( fooInstance ); // pass
expectType<Bar>( barInstance ); // pass

expectAssignable<FooBar<number>>( fooInstance ); // pass
expectAssignable<FooBar<number>>( barInstance ); // pass


type GetFoo<T> = () => Foo<T>;
type GetFooBar<T> = () => FooBar<T>;

const getFooInstance = () => fooInstance;
const getBarInstance = () => barInstance;
const getFooBarInstance = () => fooInstance as FooBar<number>;

expectType<GetFoo<number>>( getFooInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( getBarInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( getFooBarInstance ); // pass

expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( getFooInstance ); // pass
expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( getBarInstance ); // pass
expectType<GetFooBar<number>>( getFooBarInstance ); // pass


export type GetterFromFooBar<R,T1,T2 extends GetFooBar<T1>> =
  [T2] extends [GetFoo<T1>]
    ? GetFoo<R>
    : GetFooBar<R>;

// How to fix this function to properly narrow down return type to GetFoo
// when given a getter of type GetFoo,
// without requiring explicit type parameters at call site?
function processFooBar<R,T1,T2 extends GetFooBar<T1>>(
  getter: T2,
  mapper: (input: T1) => R
) {
  return (() => {
    const fooBar = getter();
    return (fooBar.foo ? ({ foo: true, value: mapper(fooBar.value) }) : ({ foo: false }) );
  }) as GetterFromFooBar<R,T1,T2>;
}

expectType<GetFoo<number>>( processFooBar<number, number, GetFoo<number>>(getFooInstance, x => x) ); // pass, explicit types
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( processFooBar<number, number, GetFooBar<number>>(getBarInstance, x => x) ); // pass, explicit types
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( processFooBar<number, number, GetFooBar<number>>(getFooBarInstance, x => x) ); // pass, explicit types

expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( processFooBar<number, number, GetFoo<number>>(getFooInstance, x => x) ); // pass, explicit types
expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( processFooBar<number, number, GetFooBar<number>>(getBarInstance, x => x) ); // pass, explicit types
expectType<GetFooBar<number>>( processFooBar<number, number, GetFooBar<number>>(getFooBarInstance, x => x) ); // pass, explicit types

expectType<GetFoo<number>>( processFooBar(getFooInstance, x => x) ); // Argument of type 'GetFoo<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetFoo<number>'.
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( processFooBar(getBarInstance, x => x) ); // pass, but GetFooBar<unknown> is nat expected
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( processFooBar(getFooBarInstance, x => x) ); // pass, but GetFooBar<unknown> is not expected

expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( processFooBar(getFooInstance, x => x) ); // Argument of type 'GetFoo<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetFooBar<number>'.
expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( processFooBar(getBarInstance, x => x) ); // Argument of type 'GetFooBar<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetFooBar<number>'.
expectType<GetFooBar<number>>( processFooBar(getFooBarInstance, x => x) ); // Argument of type 'GetFooBar<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetFooBar<number>'.
```

- Is there a way to get the desired behavior while preserving meaningful return type names (`GetFoo` rather than `() => Foo`) and without requiring to specify type parameters when calling the function? (Preferably without external dependencies.)
- or is it just not implemented yet?
- or is it a bug?

I know it should be possible to just define function overloads in this simple example. That's actually how my actual code currently works. But it shows its limits elsewhere and I thought I'd try to introduce some smarter type inference.

---

---

Below is the simpler code I provided initially.

```js
import { expectAssignable, expectNotType, expectType } from 'tsd';

type Foo = { foo: true, value: string };
type Bar = { foo: false };
type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

const fooInstance: Foo = { foo: true, value: '' };
const barInstance: Bar = { foo: false };

expectType<Foo>( fooInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<Foo>( barInstance ); // pass

expectNotType<Bar>( fooInstance ); // pass
expectType<Bar>( barInstance ); // pass

expectAssignable<FooBar>( fooInstance ); // pass
expectAssignable<FooBar>( barInstance ); // pass


type GetFoo = () => Foo;
type GetBar = () => Bar;
type GetFooBar = () => FooBar;

const getFooInstance = () => fooInstance;
const getBarInstance = () => barInstance;
const getFooBarInstance = () => fooInstance as Foo | Bar;

expectType<GetFoo>( getFooInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<GetFoo>( getBarInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<GetFoo>( getFooBarInstance ); // pass

expectNotType<GetBar>( getFooInstance ); // pass
expectType<GetBar>( getBarInstance ); // pass
expectNotType<GetBar>( getFooBarInstance ); // pass

expectAssignable<GetFooBar>( getFooInstance ); // pass
expectAssignable<GetFooBar>( getBarInstance ); // pass
expectType<GetFooBar>( getFooBarInstance ); // pass


export type GetterFromFooBar<T extends FooBar> = T extends Foo ? GetFoo : GetFooBar;

// How to fix this function to properly narrow down return type to GetFoo when given a getter of type GetFoo?
// Inlining GetterFromFooBar just changes the inferred type to GetFooBar.
function processFooBar(getter: GetFooBar) : GetterFromFooBar<ReturnType<typeof getter>> {
  return getter;
}

expectType<GetFoo>( processFooBar(getFooInstance) ); // Argument of type 'GetFoo | GetFooBar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetFoo'.
expectNotType<GetFoo>( processFooBar(getBarInstance) ); // pass, but for wrong reason
expectNotType<GetFoo>( processFooBar(getFooBarInstance) ); // pass, but for wrong reason

expectNotType<GetBar>( processFooBar(getFooInstance) ); // pass, but for wrong reason
expectType<GetBar>( processFooBar(getBarInstance) ); // Argument of type 'GetFoo | GetFooBar' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GetBar'.
expectNotType<GetBar>( processFooBar(getFooBarInstance) ); // pass, but for wrong reason

expectAssignable<GetFooBar>( processFooBar(getFooInstance) ); // pass, but for wrong reason
expectAssignable<GetFooBar>( processFooBar(getBarInstance) ); // pass, but for wrong reason
expectType<GetFooBar>( processFooBar(getFooBarInstance) ); // Parameter type GetFooBar is not identical to argument type GetFoo | GetFooBar.
```

@ghybs and @jcalz offered a solution that doesn't preserve the named return type and doesn't seem to be possible to modify to have return type to be derived rather than equal to input type:

```js
function processFooBar<T extends FooBar>(getter: () => T): () => T {
    return getter;
}
```

@jcalz offered a working solution like this:

```js
export type GetterFromFooBar<T extends FooBar> = 
    [T] extends [Foo] ? GetFoo : 
    [T] extends [Bar] ? GetBar :
    GetFooBar;

function processFooBar<T extends FooBar>(getter: () => T) {
    return getter as GetterFromFooBar<T>;
}
```

Unfortunately, I oversimplified the initial example, and this wasn't the entirety of my issue.

Comment: Any specific reason for not using a generic type parameter, e.g. like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wvayrm)? Let me know if I should write a more detailed answer, or what is specific to your case that is not addressed.

Comment: `processFooBar()` needs to be generic (or overloaded) in order for the return type to depend on inputs.  The example code seems like it should be changed to [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/WylzKm) but I assume you have some reason for using those conditional types?  If so, could you motivate them?

Comment: Actual Foo, GetFoo and GetBar all generics on their own, GetFoo and GetBar accept some arguments. Your solutions seem to work in passing the test, but it has an ergonomics issue, that is it loses meaningful names GetFoo or GetFooBar. Actual type definitions, pretty long already, are going to be even worse and exposing some implementation details more than necessary.

Comment: Next thing I was going to do is to see whether I can narrow the return type based on whether any of input functions array has the type GetFoo...
I think I've seen utility types like All/Any somewhere. But this all starts to look unfeasible.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzaD4m) work for you then?  If so I can write up an answer explaining; (please mention @jcalz if you reply, or I won't be notified)

Comment: Interesting. I updated the code to include some generics to make it closer to the original code. No idea how to make short URL from playground, so here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/KillyMXI/6566cf2cd61a89e1f79ce13760223c93  The issue now is that the function `processFooBar` cannot be called without explicit type arguments, which is not acceptable. Not sure whether that can be further improved.

Comment: Btw, I've written down the issue in the repo of the actual code: https://github.com/mxxii/peberminta/issues/67  The example in this question is based on the `map` function.

Comment: Should I answer the question as asked with the code I suggested?  If so, let me know.  If not, please [edit] the code in the question if the current example there doesn't represent your issue (although I'm a little concerned that if I make a suggestion you'll modify the code further because of it).  Again, if you want to notify me, *please* write "@jcalz" in your response.  I'm unlikely to check back here again otherwise.

Comment: @jcalz I'll edit the question. There is the end goal for my question, I just failed to keep the right amount of important detail when condensed it for the question.

Comment: @jcalz I updated the question, in case you have more ideas for a solution. I don't think I have any details left out for further editing. If there will be other questions down the line - they're more likely to be separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

No need for utility types - it is possible to infer everything into optional type parameters.

```js
function processFooBar<
  R2,
  TGetter1 extends GetFooBar<any>,
  R1 = TGetter1 extends GetFooBar<infer T> ? T : never,
  TGetter2 = TGetter1 extends GetFoo<R1> ? GetFoo<R2> : GetFooBar<R2>
>(
  getter: TGetter1,
  mapper: (input: R1) => R2
) {
  return (() => {
    const fooBar = getter();
    return fooBar.foo ?
      { foo: true, value: mapper(fooBar.value as R1) }
      : { foo: false };
  }) as TGetter2;
}

const getFooInstanceWrapped = processFooBar(getFooInstance, x => x);
const getBarInstanceWrapped = processFooBar(getBarInstance, x => x);
const getFooBarInstanceWrapped = processFooBar(getFooBarInstance, x => x);

expectType<GetFoo<number>>( getFooInstanceWrapped ); // pass
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( getBarInstanceWrapped ); // pass
expectNotType<GetFoo<number>>( getFooBarInstanceWrapped ); // pass

expectAssignable<GetFooBar<number>>( getFooInstanceWrapped ); // pass
expectType<GetFooBar<unknown>>( getBarInstanceWrapped ); // pass (Bar has no generic type attached to it so it is expected this way without extra hints)
expectType<GetFooBar<number>>( getFooBarInstanceWrapped ); // pass
```

Ordering of type parameters is not pretty. It is possible to bring `TMapper` into type parameters and derive `R2` from that for a more natural ordering.

Definition of `processFooBar` starts to look quite scary, but type resolution for inputs and outputs works as expected.

---

Update: While this solves the question the way I formulated it, there is still no full parity with function overloading - this may collapse generic parameters earlier than needed when they are not inferable from arguments, whilst function overloading keeps generic parameters.